# Sapply dataframe column assignment

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, assign, sapply

I want to rewrite some of the first lines from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618556/export-data-frames-to-excel-via-xlsx-with-conditional-formatting/21671718), and I can't figure out why my `sapply` line isn't working.

I want to turn these lines:

```
cols <- sample(c(1:5), 1)
label <- rep(paste0("label ", seq(from=1, to=10)))
mydata <- data.frame(label)
for (i in 1:cols) {mydata[,i+1] <- sample(c(1:10), 10)}
```

into:

```
cols <- sample(c(1:5), 1) 
mydata <- data.frame(rep(paste0("label ", seq(1,10))))
sapply(1:cols, function(x) { mydata[,(x+1)] <- sample(c(1:10), 10) } )
```

but for some reason that `sapply` line gives me a `new columns would leave holes after existing columns` error, and I don't know why.

I've also tried

```
sapply(1:cols, function(x) { mydata[,(x+1)] <- sample(c(1:10), 10); mydata } )
Map(function(x, mydata1) {mydata1[,(x+1)] <- sample(c(1:10), 10)}, x = 1:cols, mydata1 = mydata)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to determine why your code wasn't working, but it has something to do with the columns not being defined before you run `sapply`.  So if you define your `data.frame` beforehand, it works

```
cols <- sample(c(1:5), 1) 
mydata <- data.frame(matrix(rep(0, 10*(cols+1)), ncol = cols+1))
mydata[, 1] <- rep(paste0("label ", seq(1,10)))
sapply(1:cols, function(x) {
  mydata[, x+1] <- sample(c(1:10), 10) } )
```

## EDIT:

You can use the following code instead

```
cols <- sample(c(1:5), 1) 
mydata <- data.frame(rep(paste0("label ", seq(1,10))),
                     sapply(1:cols, function(x) {sample(c(1:10), 10) } ))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting. It definitely has something to do how a dataframe is technically a list. The output of that sapply function is a matrix, though, and doesn't have any of the labels.

Comment: This works, though: `cols <- sample(c(1:5), 1); 
mydata <- matrix(rep(0, 10*(cols)), ncol = cols);
mydata <- sapply(1:cols, function(x) mydata[, x] <- sample(c(1:10), 10));
mydata <- data.frame(rep(paste0("label ", seq(1,10))), mydata)`

Comment: @smanski provided me with a very elegant solution in two lines that works fine for me. Your answer was helpful too, which is why I upvoted it, but your solution is much less concise.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking specifically about the portion of @smanski's answer that he added in an edit.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

When you assign new column in the `mydata` dataframe, it does it locally to the function. Any changes to the `mydata` dataframe does not apply in the parent environment of this function.

To see this effect, use a `print` statement inside the function.

```
mydata <- data.frame( label = rep(paste0("label ", seq(1,10))))
sapply( 1:cols, function(x) { 
  mydata[[(x+1)]] <- sample(c(1:10), 10)
  print(mydata)
  } )
mydata
```

To prevent this scoping issue you can use `<<-` instead of `<-`.

```
sapply(1:cols, function(x) { mydata[,(x+1)] <<- sample(c(1:10), 10) } )
```

Note: using `<<-` approach is strongly discouraged due to confusions created later by it, when your code base grows and your computations involve multiple packages.

**Possible Solution:**

You have take the output of the `sapply` command and column bind with the `mydata`.

Try this:

```
set.seed(1L)
cols <- sample(c(1:5), 1) 
print(cols) # [1] 2
mydata <- data.frame( label = rep(paste0("label ", seq(1,10))))
do.call("cbind",
        list( mydata,
              sapply( seq_len(cols), function(x) sample(c(1:10), 10) )
        ))
```

Output:

```
#     label    1  2
# 1   label 1  4  2
# 2   label 2  6  7
# 3   label 3  8  4
# 4   label 4  2  6
# 5   label 5  9  3
# 6   label 6  5  8
# 7   label 7  3  5
# 8   label 8  7 10
# 9   label 9  1  9
# 10 label 10 10  1
```