# How can i color code a column in R when outputting an excel file?

Tags: r

hello good morning i wanted to if you are able to color code a column in R, when outputting an excel file? for example when i output the excel file and open it the column i want to be colored id the color blue.

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618556/export-data-frames-to-excel-via-xlsx-with-conditional-formatting

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, [edit] your question and show the code you are using to output the data, in particular which package are you using for creating Excel files. Thank you.

Comment: What packages are you using? What have you tried? If you have nothing so far ... check out [`openxlsx`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/), and specifically its [vignette on formatting](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/vignettes/formatting.pdf).